# A bat script to remove part of file name that always the same

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a bat file to remove -en-us from this mutiple files:

ie. monthly sales and cancellations-en-us.pdf  would be renamed to monthly sales and cancellations.pdf.

This script below would work on local machine. However, if I define a filesharelocation which is a shared drive, and run it then I got this error:

File Not Found
The system cannot find the file specified.

Below is the script i'm using:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set deletestring=-en-us
set filesharelocation=\\companyname\DEV\Testing
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir %filesharelocation% /b /l *-en-us.pdf ^| find "%deletestring%"') do (
    set oldfilename=%%F
    set newfilename=!oldfilename:%deletestring%=!
    Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
    )
```

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As it is coded, `%%F` returns the content in the output of `dir` command, that is, only the file name without path.

If it is executed from the same directory that contains the files, there is no problem, but when you run it agains the content of other drive/folder, as `%%F` does not contain the path to the file, and the files are not in the same folder than the batch file, the line

```
Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
```

(with oldfilename obtained from %%F) does not contain any path, only filenames.

Simplest solution is to add the path.

```
Ren "%filesharelocation%\!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
```

or, you can change the current drive to the folder with files

```
pushd "%filesharelocation%"
for /f "delims==" %%F in .....
    .....
)
popd
```

Comment: Thanks, using this works:
pushd "%filesharelocation%"
for /f "delims==" %%F in .....
    .....
)
popd